# Get All children, children of children in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So far i have tried this  to get all children of the object but it is only brings two child object. Not all child of the child. how do i get all and loop through to get specific name object

```
Transform[] objChild = gameObject.transform.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
for (var i = 0; i < objChild.Length; i++)
{
    objWheel.Add(objChild[i].gameObject.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject);
    objWheelAnimation.Add(objChild[i].gameObject.transform.GetChild(i).GetComponent<Animation>());
    if (objChild[i].gameObject.name.Contains("Wheel Rotation"))
    {               
    }
}
```

Comment: Im not familiar with unity, but it sounds `gameObject.transform.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();` is not an recursive method. Can you post the code of named method?

Comment: @lokusking That function is a unity function that returns all first level childs of the respective gameobject, so no, it is not recursive.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to get each and every child of a parent GameObject then, [Here is the smallest and simple code snippet](https://youtu.be/PclIygjZ-VY). Attach this to the parent GameObject.

```
        foreach (Transform g in transform.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>())
        {
            Debug.Log(g.name);
        }
```

Answer (score 10):

You must use recursivity:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

private List<GameObject> listOfChildren;
private void GetChildRecursive(GameObject obj){
    if (null == obj)
        return;

    foreach (Transform child in obj.transform){
        if (null == child)
            continue;
        //child.gameobject contains the current child you can do whatever you want like add it to an array
        listOfChildren.Add(child.gameObject);
        GetChildRecursive(child.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: Why `using System.Collections.Generic` ?

Comment: It includes List type but you can create a simple array of GameObject if you know the number of children.

Comment: I used recursive method to find all gameobjects and then the program freezes.

Comment: I don't why this only works when I declare my `List` as a SerializeField.

Answer (score 3):

Documentation on [GetComponentsInChildren](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentsInChildren.html)
says it works recursively. Maybe it's worth to check hierrarchy or whether or not your objects are active?

Answer (score 0):

This may not work for everyone, but here's a method that I discovered that worked well for my purposes, and is extremely simple. It gets every child, and every child of that child:

I'm using it to change the layer of everything, but it should require minimal changes to get it working for any purpose

```
void SetChildLayers (Transform trans, int layer)
    {
        
        //foreach transform, set each transform to layer of layer

        //also foreach transform, check if that transform has children. If it does, loop this code back with the new transform 

        foreach (Transform t in trans)
        {

            t.gameObject.layer = layer;

            if (t.childCount != 0)
            {
                SetChildLayers(t, layer);
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a simple way to solve this

```
ChangeChildLayer(Transform Obj)
{     
    foreach (Transform Child in Obj)
        Child.gameObject.layer = LayerMask.Name.NameToLayer("Inventory");

    if(Child.transform.ChildCount>0)
    {
        ChangeChildLayer(Child)
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Pass as argument the transform of the game object that is parent to the children you want to find. The method returns all children.

```
public static List<GameObject> GetAllChildren(this Transform aParent)
{
    List<GameObject> children = new List<GameObject>();

    Queue<Transform> queue = new Queue<Transform>();
    queue.Enqueue(aParent);
    while (queue.Count > 0)
    {
        var c = queue.Dequeue();

        children.Add(c.gameObject);

        foreach (Transform t in c)
            queue.Enqueue(t);
    }

    return children;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I always used recursion until Unity added the ability to get all children GetcomponentsInChildren as suggested by Muhammad.
To also include deactivated child game objects you must pass in true when calling GetComponentsInChildren(true)